# How to convert 'NaN' strings in a pandas Series to null values for dropna?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I tried a couple methods to clean rows containing `NaN` from a particular Series in my DataFrame only to realize every `NaN` entry is a `'NaN'` string, not a null value.

In my specific example, each row represents a country and so I want to remove all countries that do not have a GDP value in the `'GDP per Capita'` column from the DataFrame.

Some things I tried (that failed):

```
df_noGDP = df
df_noGDP.dropna(axis=0, subset=['GDP per Capita'])
```

and

```
df_noGDP = df.loc[df['GDP per Capita'] != np.nan]
```

When I call `df_noGDP`, I see that no `NaN` values are removed. I figure I'm either making a silly syntax error somewhere or I need to convert my data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert your strings to `NaN` values:

```
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
```

Then assign back *or* specify your method to be in-place:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['GDP per Capita'])           # not in place version
df.dropna(subset=['GDP per Capita'], inplace=True)  # in place version
```

Alternatively, use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html), since `NaN != NaN` [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values):

```
df = df.loc[df['GDP per Capita'].notnull()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
df_noGDP=df_noGDP.replace('NaN',np.nan)
```

Or:

```
df_noGDP.replace('NaN','np.nan,inplace=1)
```

Then your stuff would work as expected.